# Convergence of in $L_1$ and probability

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n → 0$ (converges in probability. Then show that if $|X_n | ≤ A$, for some $A > 0$ and all $n$, then $E[|X_n |] → 0$ and $E[X_n ] → 0$.

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: As $X_n$ converges in probability, $P(|X_n| > \epsilon) ->0$. By Markov inequality, $P(|X_n| > \epsilon) < E(X_n)/ \epsilon$. Therefore, $E(|X_n|)>0$?

Comment: @saz please provide some direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix any $\varepsilon>0$, and observe that
$$
\mathbb{E}|X_n| = \int_{|X_n| > \varepsilon} |X_n| d \mathbb{P} + \int_{|X_n| \leq \varepsilon} |X_n| d \mathbb{P}  \leq A \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \varepsilon) + \varepsilon.
$$

Now use the fact that $X_n \to 0$ in probability, and that $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary.

Comment: So $E|X_n| -> \epsilon$ ?

Comment: @Christy, from the displayed inequality, applying limits on both sides we get $$ \limsup\limits_{n \to\infty } \mathbb{E}|X_n| \leq \varepsilon  \ \ (1) $$  thanks to the condition $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \varepsilon ) \to 0$ (convergence of $X_n$ to $0$ in probability). Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, the inequality $(1)$  implies that the $\lim \mathbb{E}|X_n| $ exists and equals $0$.